# Using a Roth conversion ladder in a 401(k) while also retaining backdoor Roth IRA conversions

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-ira, roth-conversion

Consider the following scenario:

- John Q. Public has a high enough MAGI that he is not eligible to make Roth IRA contributions (and hence also cannot deduct traditional IRA contributions).
- John also has an employer-provided 401(k) with the following features:

  - A Roth 401(k) is available.
  - In-plan Roth conversions are available.
  - The plan can be retained even after John ceases to be employed.
  - Cessation of employment makes John eligible for distributions from the 401(k), subject to the usual penalties.
- John wishes to retire prior to the age of 59½, meaning that he will not have access to anything in his 401(k) or IRA, with the exception of Roth principal that has had 5 years to season.
- John, like all rational actors, wishes to avoid taxes to the extent permitted by law.

Given this scenario, consider the following plan:

- John never contributes to a traditional IRA, except to make contributions that are immediately backdoored into a Roth IRA. **This ensures that John never pays taxes pro rata on the traditional fraction of his IRA balance.**
- While John is employed, John makes yearly backdoor Roth IRA contributions and traditional 401(k) contributions up to the IRS limit. **This saves John taxes at his marginal rate on the amount contributed to the 401(k).**
- John quits his job sometime before the age of 59½.
- Starting in the year he quits, and continuing for 5 years, John subsists on money from taxable accounts, plus Roth IRA principal, plus 5-year-seasoned earnings from his Roth IRA. **John only pays long term capital gains taxes on money from his taxable accounts, which could be $0 if John's taxable income stays within the 15% bracket.**
- Starting in the year he quits, and continuing until he turns 54½, John performs an in-plan conversion on his 401(k) to bring his income up to some suitable level (say, the top of the 15% income bracket, or whatever its future equivalent is). **John pays regular income taxes on the converted amount, at a low marginal rate.**
- Starting 5 years after he quits, and continuing until he turns 59½, John subsists on whatever principal plus 5-year-seasoned earnings is left in his Roth IRA, plus the newly-available principal plus 5-year-seasoned earnings from his converted Roth 401(k). **John pays no taxes on this specifically, but continues to pay taxes on the ongoing conversions (above) until he turns 54½.**
- Starting when John turns 59½, he does whatever, since all his retirement savings are now available.

My question is basically "does that all sound right?".

The reason I ask is that under most circumstances, backdoor Roth IRA contributions are incompatible with a Roth conversion ladder. For the former, you want to have zero traditional IRA assets so you're not taxed on the conversion; for the latter, you obviously have to have tax-deferred assets to convert.

However, by putting the tax-deferred assets into a 401(k) and doing the entirety of the laddering within the 401(k), it seems like you can both have your cake and eat it, too - you can do backdoor Roth IRAs without ever paying the pro rata tax on the traditional fraction of your total IRA balances and still have a ladder going within the 401(k).

So - does that all sound right?

(I'm aware that there's risk involved in this plan if Congress decides to make changes to how retirement account taxes work; ignore that for now and assume that current tax law prevails for the rest of time.)

Comment: by the way, there is no such thing as "5-year-seasoned principal from his Roth IRA". Principal from Roth IRA can be withdrawn at any time for any reason without tax or penalty.

Comment: @user102008 Thanks, I goofed that while I was moving things around.

Comment: John can withdraw penalty free if he retires from that job after age 55.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is right.  It is what I am doing.

In fact, I took it one step further.  During my early career when I was able to deduct traditional IRA contributions, I made them and saved on taxes.  When my income got high enough that I could no longer deduct those contributions, I rolled all my traditional IRA's into my 401(k).  Now they are no longer subject to the pro-rata rule and I could begin with the backdoor Roths while continuing to contribute the max to my traditional 401(k). Thereafter it's pretty much the process you have described.